# How to do sum of the two different time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have the following code :

```
SELECT distinct userinfo.userid,userinfo.name,timeframe,deptname from EarlyOut
INNER JOIN userinfo ON USERINFO.USERID = earlyout.USERID
INNDER JOIN DEPARTMENTS ON DEPARTMENTS.DEPTID = EarlyOut.DEFAULTDEPTID
 where date>='2015-02-01' and date<='2015-02-28' and
DEPARTMENTS.DEPTNAME = 'abc'
```

Now from above code i am getting following answer:

```
userid  name    timeframe             deptname
111     xyz     2015-02-05 08:00:00    abc 
111     xyz     2015-02-10 09:15:00    abc
```

Now i want the `following` output:

```
userid  name    timeframe             deptname
111     xyz     17:15:00                abc
```

I want the total of time

So How can i do that?

Comment: If you're storing *amount* of time, why are you storing it as `DATETIME`?

Comment: For instance, can you elaborate on what the purpose of the `timeframe` field is, and why you're not storing it as a numeric field with the values `8` and  `9.25` respectively?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I can't answer for deepak. But datetime is in my opinion the best way to store time if the time can be 24 hours or more. 2 days 4 hours 10 minutes 5 seconds would be 1900-03-03 04:10:05

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT userinfo.userid,
                userinfo.name,
                Dateadd(ms, Sum(Datediff(ms, '00:00:00.000', timeframe)), '00:00:00.000') AS newtimeframe,
                deptname
FROM   EarlyOut
       INNER JOIN userinfo
               ON USERINFO.USERID = earlyout.USERID
       INNER JOIN DEPARTMENTS
               ON DEPARTMENTS.DEPTID = EarlyOut.DEFAULTDEPTID
WHERE  date >= '2015-02-01'
       AND date <= '2015-02-28'
       AND DEPARTMENTS.DEPTNAME = 'abc'
GROUP  BY userinfo.userid,
          userinfo.name,
          DEPARTMENTS.DEPTNAME
```

Comment: Can you explain what's going on really i didn't understand anything